# Meaning of "[A-Z]{4}\d{2}-\d{4}" in an XSD pattern

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

Can someone please explain me the meaning of this pattern with a example of a valid data argument.

```
<xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:pattern value="[A-Z]{4}\d{2}-\d{4}"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: 4 uppercase characters followed by 2 digits then a hyphen then another 4 digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are examples:

Valid

```
FOOB45-9876
BAZZ36-1726
```

Not valid

```
foob47-8372 // may not contain lowercase letters
FOO36-8373  // only 3 starting characters
FOOB29_8473 // underscore instead of hyphen
FOOBa3-8272 // must contain two numbers before the hyphen
```

And so on.

As @Petru Gardea commented, XSD's flavour of regex implicitly anchors with ^ and $, which means both `FFOOB45-9876` and `FOOB45-98767` would be invalid, whereas all other regex engines (that we know) would actually match them.

Comment: I would add that XSD's flavour of regex implicitly anchors with ^ and $, which means both FFOOB45-9876 and FOOB45-98767 would be invalid, whereas all other regex engines (that I know) would actually match them.

Comment: Thanks @PetruGardea, added it to the answer!